# Bubble Sort not Sorting One Element

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I have two Methods which have to be void methods, they are using a propriety from the elements in the list named Magnitude to sort them using bubble sort from the smallest to largest, the method OnePassBubbleSort orders one element at a time
and sortByMagnitudeWithBubbleSort runs the sorting the times needed to get to get the answer the problem is that the quake with magnitude 2.6 does not seem to order properly.

my code is
[this](http://codepaste.net/wbmgw2):

```
public void onePassBubbleSort(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> quakes, int numSorted) {
    int minIdx = 0;
    for (int i=0 + 1; i< quakes.size()-numSorted; i++) {

        if (quakes.get(i).getMagnitude() < quakes.get(minIdx).getMagnitude()) {
            QuakeEntry qi = quakes.get(i);
            QuakeEntry qmin = quakes.get(minIdx);
            quakes.set(i,qmin);
            quakes.set(minIdx,qi);
            minIdx = i;            
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Printing Quakes after pass " + numSorted );  
    for(QuakeEntry qe: quakes){
        System.out.println(qe.toString());
    }

}

public void sortByMagnitudeWithBubbleSort(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> in) {

   for (int i=0; i< in.size()-1; i++) {
        onePassBubbleSort(in,i);   
    } 
}
```

the original data is

- (-23.27, -67.66), mag = 4.80, depth = -175320.00, title = 69km SE of San Pedro de Atacama, Chile
- (35.68, -118.10), mag = 1.50, depth = -8280.00, title = 27km W of Inyokern, California
- (36.22, -117.89), mag = 2.60, depth = -1450.00, title = 12km ESE of Olancha, California
- (36.95, -121.57), mag = 1.00, depth = -8660.00, title = 6km S of Gilroy, California
- (38.82, -122.77), mag = 1.40, depth = -1300.00, title = 3km W of Cobb, California

and my result output is

1. (36.95, -121.57), mag = 1.00, depth = -8660.00, title = 6km S of Gilroy, California
2. (36.22, -117.89), mag = 2.60, depth = -1450.00, title = 12km ESE of Olancha, California
3. (38.82, -122.77), mag = 1.40, depth = -1300.00, title = 3km W of Cobb, California
4. (35.68, -118.10), mag = 1.50, depth = -8280.00, title = 27km W of Inyokern, California
5. (-23.27, -67.66), mag = 4.80, depth = -175320.00, title = 69km SE of San Pedro de Atacama, Chile

my guess is that I have to return the list from the onepassbubblesort, and run that list again, but I that cannot be done with void methods

Comment: What is one pass bubble sort? Is it only single iteraton of bubble sorting? Than in most cases it is not sorting at all, only moving single element. Cant you use `Collections.sort()` ??

Comment: one pass bubble sort iterates over the whole list with the purpose of moving the biggest element to the end of it, and I can not use libraries apart from the ones provided for this exercise.

Comment: As for returning lists and iteratinv over and over again, you dont have to return the actuall list, you can just modified the list that is passed as an argument to the metod - no return value require for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sorting method is only moving the `minIdx = i;` pointer when there is a match, causing it not to line up if the first element is smaller. Effectively, you are only swapping the first element and any other element you encountered when they match.

A fix for this would be moving the `minIdx = i;` outside the if statement so it will always get called:

```
for (int i=0 + 1; i< quakes.size()-numSorted; i++) {

    if (quakes.get(i).getMagnitude() < quakes.get(minIdx).getMagnitude()) {
        QuakeEntry qi = quakes.get(i);
        QuakeEntry qmin = quakes.get(minIdx);
        quakes.set(i,qmin);
        quakes.set(minIdx,qi);        
    }
    minIdx = i;  
}
```

Because the way you coded you function to accept a `numSorted` argument, another solution to the problem would be assigment `minIdx` to this variable:

```
minIdx = numSorted;
```

Comment: you are right sir, thank you I was losing it over something that looked so simple.